# Is it possible to get tethered focus and aperture control with any current DSLR?

Tags: focus, depth-of-field, tethering, camera-controls, programming

I'm looking to get into some photography work and I had a couple questions. I'm quite an amateur at this, unfortunately, so I would appreciate any and all assistance!

I want to be able to control the focus and aperture of a DSLR from my laptop while streaming images from the camera. Is this possible? If so, what would I need to do/get in order to do this? Particularly, I want to be able to do this from code so that I can take sets of images at different focus/aperture settings in succession and do processing on them within my code.

Comment: Do you have a buget or operating system requirement?

Comment: Operating system: Not really, I can run Linux, Windows, or Mac OS X.
Budget: Ideally I'd like to be able to use the Canon 5D Mark II I currently have access to, but acquiring a new camera isn't a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at [DSLR Remote Pro](http://www.breezesys.com/DSLRRemotePro/features.htm). As described on the features page:

> DSLR Remote Pro for Windows also includes a DLL and a sample program
>   (complete with C++ source code) which allows other applications to
>   release the camera's shutter and adjust the shutter speed and
>   aperture.

The software supports most Canon DSLR cameras, the 5D Mk II that you already have access to included.

For more details I would check out the help file [here](http://www.breezesys.com/DSLRRemotePro/help/index.html), then click on "Running DSLR Remote Pro from other apps" from the navigation on the left.

Comment: Ahh, thanks! I took a look at that and I'm not sure that they show code for adjusting focus.
I've also found this function in the Canon EOS SDK: kEdsCameraCommand_DriveLensEvf 
This supposedly will let me drive the lens and adjust focus. I don't have access to the Canon 5D Mk2 just yet, but I'll try this (and DSLR Remote Pro) out once I get my hands on it.

Thanks again for the pointer!